# How do I create multiple headers with column span in Material-UI DataGrid in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How do I create multiple headers with column span in Material-UI DataGrid?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejB6P.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think what you want is something like this but for DataGrid, no? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-r1p51?file=/demo.js

Comment: See here for a preview of the feature: https://deploy-preview-5133--material-ui-x.netlify.app/x/react-data-grid/column-groups/ being tracked by this GitHub issue: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/295

Comment: Actually, it's been released. I think this is what you want: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-groups/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom toolbar to achieve your goal. [Here's](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#toolbar) the documentation on how to

Example

```js
const CustomToolbar = (props) => <h1>I'm a custom toolbar</h1>;

export default function ToolbarGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        {...data}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This just creates a toolbar, it doesn't add another header row to the table.